# How do I prevent Unity from freezing during gameplay in a 2D scene?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

While I'm playing in a scene in Unity, the game freezes. I have this code:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlatformManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] platformPrefabs;
    [SerializeField] private Transform player;
    [SerializeField] private float spawnDistance = 10f;
    [SerializeField] private float platformWidth = 4f;

    private float lastSpawnPositionY = -4.5f;
    private float lastSpawnPositionX = 0f;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        Destroy(collision.gameObject);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (player.position.y > lastSpawnPositionY - spawnDistance)
        {
            SpawnPlatform();
        }
    }

    private void SpawnPlatform()
    {
        float randomX1 = GetRandomXPosition();
        float randomX2 = GetRandomXPosition();
        float randomY1 = lastSpawnPositionY + Random.Range(1.5f, 2.7f);
        float randomY2 = randomY1 + Random.Range(0.2f, 0.5f);

        while (Mathf.Abs(randomX1 - randomX2) < platformWidth)
        {
            randomX2 = GetRandomXPosition();
        }

        Vector2 spawnPosition1 = new Vector2(randomX1, randomY1);
        Vector2 spawnPosition2 = new Vector2(randomX2, randomY2);

        int platformIndex = GetRandomPlatformIndex();
        GameObject platformPrefab = platformPrefabs[platformIndex];

        Instantiate(platformPrefab, spawnPosition1, Quaternion.identity);
        Instantiate(platformPrefabs[0], spawnPosition2, Quaternion.identity);

        lastSpawnPositionY = Mathf.Max(randomY1, randomY2);
        lastSpawnPositionX = Mathf.Max(randomX1, randomX2);
    }

    private float GetRandomXPosition()
    {
        float randomX = Random.Range(-7f, 7f);

        while (Mathf.Abs(randomX - lastSpawnPositionX) < platformWidth)
        {
            randomX = Random.Range(-7f, 7f);
        }

        return randomX;
    }

    private int GetRandomPlatformIndex()
    {
        float[] probabilities = { 0.1f, 0.05f, 0.03f, 0.1f, 0.05f };
        float totalProbability = 0f;

        foreach (float probability in probabilities)
        {
            totalProbability += probability;
        }

        float randomValue = Random.Range(0f, totalProbability);
        float cumulativeProbability = 0f;

        for (int i = 0; i < probabilities.Length; i++)
        {
            cumulativeProbability += probabilities[i];

            if (randomValue <= cumulativeProbability)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
}
```

This is the code that generates platforms in the game. I have an object on the stage that has a Box Collider attached to it and Is Trigger Enter enabled, so I work with this method in the code. Perhaps there are problems somewhere in the code that cause Unity to freeze. And also, could you please tell me how to move platforms up using the same logic instead of deleting and re-creating them?

Comment: If you keep randomly hanging pictures on your wall, you will eventually run out of space for another picture on your wall.  As you approach running out of space it'll actually start taking longer and longer to successfully "randomly" position the picture in an empty spot on the wall as most random positions will overlap an existing picture.  Consider instead tallying up all the available empty gaps large enough for a picture, and then, checking to see if there is enough space, and if there is, then selecting a position within that range with the generation of a single random number.

Answer (score 1):

One very potential freeze are those `while` loops. What if the random generations never are able to fulfill the exit condition?

**Update**

In my previous answer I made a wrong assumption. I thought the new random positions should be in the range `-7` to `7` from the previous one. But actually that is your absolute range.

So actually for the first `randomX1` there is actually two potential ranges

- The range from `platformWidth` units left of the previous position down to `-7f`
- The range from `platformWidth` units right of the previous position up to `7f`

with the limitation that you only use a range if the range itself is actually bigger than `platformWidth`.

Here some images for better understanding the code below

[image]
[image]

So something like e.g.

```
var minPointRange1a = -7f;
var maxPointRange1a = lastSpawnPositionX - platformWidth;
var sizeRange1a = maxPointRange1a - minPointRange1a;
var range1a = Random.Range(minPointRange1a, maxPointRange1a);

var minPointRange1b = lastSpawnPositionX + platformWidth;
var maxPointRange1b = 7f;
var sizeRange1b = maxPointRange1b - minPointRange1b;
var range1b = Random.Range(minPointRange1b, maxPointRange1b);

// Is there only one option anyway?
float randomX1;
if(sizeRange1a > 0 && sizeRange1b <= 0)
{
    randomX1 = range1a;
}
else if(sizeRange1a <= 0)
{
    randomX1 = range1b;
}
else
{
    // are both possible take either the first or second option according to the size distribution between the options
    randomX1 = Random.value <= sizeRange1a / (sizeRange1a + sizeRange1b) ? range1a : range1b;
}
```

*Note: [`Random.value`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-value.html) basically equals `Random.Range(0f, 1f)`*

Then for the second value it is even bit trickier as now you have already two points you want to have a certain distance from so there are up to three ranges you could potentially place the object in

[image]
[image]

so we just have to continue checking those ranges and edge cases

```
var minPointRange2a = -7f;
var maxPointRange2a = Mathf.Min(lastSpawnPositionX, randomX1) - platformWidth;
var sizeRange2a = maxPointRange2a - minPointRange2a;
var range2a = Random.Range(minPointRange2a, maxPointRange2a);

var minPointRange2b = Mathf.Min(lastSpawnPositionX, randomX1) + platformWidth;
var maxPointRange2b = Mathf.Max(lastSpawnPositionX, randomX1) - platformWidth;
var sizeRange2b = maxPointRange2b - minPointRange2b;
var range2b = Random.Range(minPointRange2b, maxPointRange2b);

var minPointRange2c = Mathf.Max(lastSpawnPositionX, randomX1) + platformWidth;
var maxPointRange2c = 7f;
var sizeRange2c = maxPointRange2c - minPointRange2c;
var range2c = Random.Range(minPointRange2c , maxPointRange2c);

// again distributing amongst these (certainly leaving a lot potential for improvement here ^^)

var cases = 0;
if (sizeRange2a > 0) cases += 1;
if (sizeRange2b > 0) cases += 2;
if (sizeRange2c > 0) cases += 4;

float randomX2;
switch(cases)
{
    case 1: // only range2a is valid
        randomX2 = range2a;
        break;

    case 2: // only range2b is valid
        randomX2 = range2b;
        break;

    case 4: // only range2c is valid
        randomX2 = range2c;
        break;

    case 3: // range2a and range2b are valid
        randomX2 = Random.value > sizeRange2a / (sizeRange2a + sizeRange2b) ? range2b : range2a;
        break;

    case 5: // range2a and range2c are valid
        randomX2 = Random.value > sizeRange2a / (sizeRange2a + sizeRange2c) ? range2c : range2a;
        break;

    case 6: // range2b and range2c are valid
        randomX2 = Random.value > sizeRange2b / (sizeRange2b + sizeRange2c) ? range2c : range2b;
        break;

    case 7: // all three are valid
        var rnd = Random.value;
        randomX2 = rnd <= sizeRange2a / (sizeRange2a + sizeRange2b + sizeRange2c) ? range2a : rnd <= sizeRange2b / (sizeRange2a + sizeRange2b + sizeRange2c) ? range2b : range2c;
        break;

    default:
        throw new OperationInvalidException("Was not able to find any valid range for randomX2!");
}
```

This can probably / hopefully be improved somehow - there might be more elegant solutions to this, only execute `Random.Range` if actually valid and required and some calculations are intentionally repeated for better understanding - but I hope that gives you and idea